# How to effectively use static methods?

Tags: java, object, static

I am never quite sure that I am using static methods correctly. I understand how they work.

Let's say I have this class called Player(Java):

```
private int money;
private int lot;
private String piece;
private int playerNum;

public Player(String _piece, int _playerNum)
{   
    piece = _piece;
    lot = 0;
    playerNum = _playerNum;
    money = 20000;

}
public int getMoney()
{   
    return money;
}
public int getLot()
{
    return lot;
}
public String getPiece()
{
    return piece;
}
```

There are some other methods + setters, but they are specific to the player object I create, now let's say I have a static method like this:

```
private static int numOfPlayers;

public static int numPlayers()
{
   return numOfPlayers;
}
```

Where should this numOfPlayers method be placed?

Should it be put in my Player class? And should I increment the numOfPlayers varible everytime a new isntance of the player object is created?(via the constructor)

Or, should I have I have the method in my Game class as non-static and just call the method everytime I create a new Player.

Comment: I wouldn't make it static.  I would have a `List<Player> players` somewhere and the size of this would be the number of players.

Comment: Player shouldnt have static method with number of players. That is higher abstraction.

Comment: I wouldn't make this static, either. After all, you might have more than one `Game` going at a time with different numbers of players. Either have a `List` of players as Peter mentions above, or have `numPlayers()` be a non-static method of `Game`.

Comment: You *may* use a static method any time you do not need to access the contents of an object instance in order to perform the required computation, produce the desired value, etc.  This would include methods that only access static data, or methods that access no data at all, other than their parameters.  However, you would avoid static methods where you want the method functionality to differ based on different classes in a hierarchy, where a instance would be used to "select" the functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a matter of **design**, which obviously includes a lot of personal preference.

You really should have a look at the **factory design pattern**, which is a good way of handling such cases. Here, you could have a

```
public class PlayerFactory {
    private int numPlayers = 0;

    public int getNumPlayers() { ... }

    public Player makeNewPlayer(...) { ... }
}
```

that takes care of A) incrementing the player count appropriately.

Depending on your exact use case and code style, you may *prefer one variation or another*. But it is good to know these patterns and recognize them. And document them. By calling a class `SomethingFactory` you do hint for other developers that this class follows the factory pattern, for example.

Note that I did *not* need to use `static` in above example, assuming that the factory may only be instantiated once. It is common to see the constructor `private` and instead the class then has a `public static final` instance only.

You could also call this class `Game` or `Players`...

Comment: You can create whole Factory as Singleton, to avoid possible duplicate instances.

Comment: @MartinPerry that is the `public static final` approach that I discuss. However, in a service loader context, this may not be possible. These often require a parameterless public constructor.

Comment: You can have Initialize method instead of ctor

Answer (score 2):

Static fields and methods are supposed to represent stateless attributes of a class; i.e. not pertinent to a particular object.

But be careful with multithreading with statics since the whole class has to be locked rather than just one object. This can lead to *concurrency bottlenecks*.

As for your numOfPlayers, you'll probably end up having a collection of players developed somewhere else, in which case that function will be a method on that collection not in the player class.

Ideally, in my opinion at least, an individual player should not really be concerned about the players collection. Therefore a static function such as the one you propose would not be good design.

Answer (score 0):

You can create it like this:

Have `class Player` like you have

Create `class Players`

```
class Players 
{
    private List<Player> players = new List<Players>;

    public void AddPlayer(Player pl) 
    { 
        this.players.add(pl); 
    }

    public int GetPlayersCount() 
    { 
        return this.players.size(); 
    } 
}
```

If you want, you can make this class "static" using Singleton. But try to avoid static classes.

```
class Players 
{
    private List<Player> players = new List<Players>;
    private static Players instance;

    private Players () {};

    public static Players getInstance()
    {
       if (instance == null) 
       {
          instance = new Players ();
       }

       return instance;
    }

    public void AddPlayer(Player pl) 
    { 
        this.players.add(pl); 
    }

    public int GetPlayersCount() 
    { 
        return this.players.size(); 
    } 
}
```

And use it like this

```
Players players = Players.getInstance();
players.AddPlayer(....)
```

Answer (score 0):

how about you have a List of Players in your game and the number of players is the size of the List.

When you think you should use static for some functionality, don't do it!
Just play along the old rule to never use anything static until you are old and wise and where you perhaps can use it for some very special corner case.

Answer (score 0):

I would have the list of Players in another class, e.g. Game as you suggested.
Something like

```
class Game {
   private final List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();

   public int getNumOfPlayers() {
     return players.size();
   }

   public void addPlayer(final Player player) {
     players.add(player);
   }
   ...
```

You add a player via your instance of Game, `game` via `game.addPlayer(newPlayer)`, and get the number of players via `game.getNumOfPlayers()`.

The List of players is dynamically allocated.

As for *static* or *not static*, I prefer here the *non static* version, as the players are part of a Game, and one could consider they may be several games - and *players* would be part of an instance of Game.